# DEBIAN 11 - parallel user profiles

Tags: debian

I have a DEBIAN 11 installation on 1 PC - actual, no VMs (KVM, VMWare, Wine, etc.) exists.

I start a program with a license, that's OK. I suspend or power off the PC and start the program again - the system wants a new license from me.

That's not normal. Any ideas?

Comment: What are "parallel user profiles"? I seriously doubt that the distro in question is related. What program are you having issues with?

Comment: yeah, debian probably have nothing to do with this – it doesn't ship *any* software that would require a personal license, per policy. So, your question is really about the software that you're sadly not even naming. Quite possibly it's plainly a bug in that software.

Comment: your title says "Devian", your text says "Debian": Since there is also a Linux distro called "Devuan", I'm a bit hesitant to assume the title has the typo. Could you fix either your title or your text?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

That's most likely an issue with the program that requires the license, not with Debian/Devuan.

However, if you are using Wi-Fi, Debian/Devuan 11 has a new global default setting that will automatically randomize your Wi-Fi interfaces' MAC addresses for privacy, unless you explicitly specify that the MAC address should not be randomized for a particular network.

If the license-requiring application has been programmed to tie the license to the active MAC address of the primary network interface (instead of the *permanent* MAC address, system serial number, or some other persistent information), that might cause the behavior you are seeing.

To disable the MAC address randomization for a particular network, if your system is using NetworkManager, first run `nmcli c` to view the list of configured network connections. The active network connection should show in green text at the top of the list. You can use either the `NAME` of the connection or its `UUID` to modify it.

Then, run `nmcli c mod <name or UUID of the connection> 802-11-wireless.mac-address-randomization never` to disable MAC randomization for a particular wireless network.